# Dual-Boot Drive Management (Hiding/Restricting Access)

Tags: mac-osx, hard-drive, boot

I'm wondering if there's a 'best-practice' method to restrict access to the non-booted partition/drive when booted from a secondary HFS partition or a NTFS Windows partition. Basically I want users to still be able to mount their own hard drives/usb sticks but not be able to mount or access the other environments maintained on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I have the same question.  This seems like something that would be common if your are using dual-boot to migrate a program from one windows flavor to another.  You don't want to accidentally edit the "good standard" old version by accident while you are developing the new version.  Has anyone done this before?